# How to add drop shadow to UITableViewCell's divider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView like this:

[image]

I'd like to add a drop shadow to each Cell's divider, the result should look like this:

[image]

I tried this:

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, I added this code:

```
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1.7;
cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

Then it displayed like this:

[image]

Note that there's a drop shadow between the first cell and the status bar, which is unwanted.

Any idea on how to remove it? It doesn't have to build on the drop shadow code I'm using.

Comment: You should set the shadowOffset y value to be a positive value so that the shadow doesn't start from the center. At the moment, your shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0); means the shadow starts from the center and equally spaced around the cell, making it CGSizeMake(0, 5) would mean it faces the bottom which would produce what you want.

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to get pretty close to what you're looking for by setting the shadowRadius to a value less then the shadowOffset y value. For instance,

```
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
```

gives me:

[image]

This image was captured with the table view dragged down. There's no shadow above the topmost cell. 
The shadow is darker than what you're looking for, but you should be able to easily adjust that to your liking by changing the shadowOpacity.

Answer (score 2):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: method,

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPath2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.bounds];
cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath2.CGPath;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift**

```
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2)
cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.7).CGColor
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 1
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6                
cell.clipsToBounds = false
cell.layer.zPosition = 10
```

Comment: Why dont you edit the objc answer instead and add the swift version there?

Comment: Now a days most of the developers work in swift so i prefer swift

Comment: Yes, but why a new answer instead of editing the upvoted answee?

Comment: If my answer is different than another one's answer so i post my answer which i use and tested code before post here. (Is there any rules define that we can't post our answer?)