# Shadow Issue for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` and I wrote shadow code like this in its `layoutSubviews` method:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 4.0);
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
}
```

But when I run it, instead of having shadow on the edge, all the `subviews` on that cell got shadows, like the screen shot below, which is not what I was expecting.

[image]

I tried `self.contentView.layer` but then there wasn't any shadows at all.

So what do I do to have the shadows just on the bottom edge of the cell as usual? I don't want to shadow the subviews.

UPDATE:

I added all the subviews on my cell with `[cell addSubview:xxx];` directly, so they are not on `contentView` of the cell.

Comment: what thing do you want to prefer?

Comment: @JackyShek, on the bottom edge.

Comment: What about changing shadowOffSet value to 1.0? Have you tried this?

Comment: @NirmitDagly I don't think changing value would change the effective view cause I want to shadow the cell edge, not the subviews.

Comment: You can try this to add shadow at the cell's bootom edge: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569842/how-to-add-drop-shadow-to-uitableviewcells-divider

Answer (score 1):

try this one

instead of setting shadow in layoutsubView set it in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 4.0);
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

Comment: It didn't work and the shadows are still on the subviews, anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Add below code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
{
    tblCustomCell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
    tblCustomCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    tblCustomCell.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
    tblCustomCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
}
```